Flask containers on ECS Fargate are completely unresponsive
I have two tasks running in ECS Fargate, representing a basic Flask application that runs on port 5000.  My application load balancer is deregistering these tasks due to failed health checks.
The ALB deregisters the tasks in spite of the following facts:

My ECS tasks are assigned public IP addresses.
My Flask application is running. I aws ecs execute-command'ed into one of them  to confirm.
Port 5000 is called out explicitly in my ECS task definition's port mappings.
Port 5000 is called out explicitly in my ECS service's load balancer container port configuration.
My application load balancer is associated with a security group that allows TCP ingress on port 5000, and egress to 0.0.0.0/0 with ip_protocol="-1".
My application load balancer's target group allows for HTTP traffic on port 5000, with target_type=ip.
My application load balancer's listener is configured to route incoming traffic on port 80 to the target group referenced above.
My ECS tasks are deployed to public subnets with route table associations that link them to CIDR block 0.0.0.0/0.

When a task is up-and-running:

telnet and curl time out.
nmap -Pn reports that all 1,000 scanned ports are in ignored states.

Why are my ECS tasks completely unresponsive to any form of interaction whatsoever? How do I debug the issue?
EDIT: See Mark's answer below. The issue was that ECS tasks need security groups to communicate with the ALB (AWS will create useless ones for you if you don't specify them in the task definition). Then ECS needs to be able to communicate with ECR, which requires opening up egress on port 443 specifically if you don't want to use PrivateLink.

What are the security group rules, for the security group assigned to your ECS tasks? They should at a minimum have an inbound rule for port 5000 allowing traffic from the load balancer's security group ID. Also, your load balancer should have a rule allowing traffic on port 80, not port 5000.

I didn't specify any security groups explicitly at the ECS service network configuration level. I thought it would be sufficient to deploy ECS tasks to public subnets, and associate the tasks with an ALB which had security group rules that seem to have sufficient ingress/egress.  I was surprised to find that AWS created blank security groups for me at the ECS task level (which do absolutely nothing) instead of throwing an error.  I applied the ALB's SGs to the ECS task definitions directly, but the ALB still wants to kill all of the ECS tasks and the ECS tasks are still dead in the water.

You need to have two security groups, since the ALB and the ECS task need to have different ports open. Did you configure Flask to listen on the 0.0.0.0 address? Or is it listening on 127.0.0.1 or localhost or something? It will need to be app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)

If that doesn't work, you might need to look at your target group health check configuration. It's a common issue for people to have a health check path that actually gets redirected to a login page, and by default a redirect like that will cause the health check to fail.

That all makes sense.  The part I was missing was that the ECS tasks need SGs with an ALB SG source.  If you want to leave that as an answer, I'll accept it.  Thanks!  I should add that this still doesn't work: the ECS tasks fail to register with the ALB target group, and they fail right away because they can't communicate with ECR despite having explicit egress rules to allow them to talk to the public internet - but whatever.

If they can't connect o ECR, it is because you have them in a private subnet without a route to the Internet (via a NAT Gateway), or a route to an ECR VPC Gateway. Or you have them in a public subnet (with a route to an Internet Gateway), but you don't have the task definition configured to assign public IPs to the tasks.

My ECR tasks do have public IPs, and are located in public subnets with route table associations to routes associated with an internet gateway - but they still can't reach ECR.  This is probably something I should create a separate post for!

Yes please create a separate post for that. I don't understand how you got to the point of running aws ecs execute-command into one of them, and verifying flask was running, if the tasks couldn't access ECR. It seems like something changed that broke ECR access?

The issue was that the ECS tasks (by-default) need to be able to pull from ECR over the open internet, so they needed to have egress on port 443 to 0.0.0.0/0.

Yeah you would typically just leave the default outbound rule of 0.0.0.0/0 for all ports in your security group.

You need to have two security groups, one for the ALB and one for the ECS tasks, since they both need different ports open.
The ECS task should have an inbound rule allowing traffic on port 5000 from the ALB's security group ID as the source.

Thanks Mark! The key thing I needed to understand is that AWS will create default security groups for ECS tasks if you don't specify them, and that the ECS tasks still need security groups in order to communicate with the load balancers - it has nothing to do with the public/privateness of their subnets.
